# Access Multi select values in Jenkins Extended Choice Parameters plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I’m using Extended Choice Parameters named Tasks in a job and the parameter type is Multi Select ( for example with these values: Start, Go, End), now how can I access the selected options ?

Meaning I want to create conditional step with Boolean condition so in case Start option was selected do X and another one in case Go option was selected do Y,
The question is what should be the Token of the Conditional step ?

(I prefer not using script in order to get selected values.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [Conditional BuildStep plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin), you should be able to use the "Strings Match" condition to setup your conditional steps. See the screenshots below for an example:

[image]

[image]

If multiple options can be selected, you can still setup the job as describe above. The only thing you need to change is the type of condition. Instead of using String match, use Regular expression match. This way you can run multiple build steps if you have a composite value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but since it's Multi Select user can choose more than a one value and in that case the string match in your example will not work since ${TheChoice} could be equal to Start,Go and not just Start.

Comment: Just add multiple conditional build steps that match on each of the potential parameter values. Only the build step that matches the param value will run since the other conditions will be false.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, let's say user select options Start and Go, so the value of ${TheChoice} is Start,Go. now I have several conditional steps first check if ${TheChoice} equal to Start, second if ${TheChoice} equal to Go etc. but none of them will be true.

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood your requirements. I edited my answer to include multiple selections.